# How to open mailbox in PHP when there are more than 1000000 messages

Tags: php

I am developing some code in PHP where I want to read whole mailbox. Host is using zimbra mail. I'm trying to implement some bouncing cron job so it would be best if I don't delete any messages. But I have a problem since imap_open supports only 1000000 messages existing in mailbox. Is there any other way to open mailbox?

Comment: I can't even open the mailbox, so what should I loop? imap_open raise a notice and stops the code.

Comment: imap_open() does not care how big the mail box is, it just connects- what happens next is the issue

Comment: When I last checked, it stops on imap_open. I put `echo "test"; exit;` right after imap_open and it does not print this, so it must have stopped right on imap_open.